# Magento 2 - can the url_key product attribute be safely excluded from Search?

Tags: product-attribute, catalogsearch, magento2.3.5

I recently did an analysis for a client on a `Magento 2.3.5-p2` instance regarding some products being shown in Search results which didn't have the searched keywords in their `sku`, `name` and `short_description` attributes (which were the only expected searchable attributes).

The conclusion of the analysis was that the `url_key` product attribute caused the issue. It seems that it is fixed as a `Searchable` attribute - which can't be changed from Magento Admin.

The issue was mostly caused by URL keys from configurable variations which had some extra words in them.

I changed the value in the database (`catalog_eav_attribute` table) for this attribute on a test shop instance and the Search functionality seems to work just fine now.

So my question is, will disabling `url_key` from Search cause new problems down the road? And why is it disabled in Magento admin?